# Gnuplot Shell Script

Tags: shell, shell-script, gnuplot

I was making this shell script to become faster in plotting data with gnuplot. It is the first s.s that I write so I'm having some difficulties. All was good until I started to make the if statement. Now executing this returns this error:

```
prova2.sh: 53: prova2.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

This is an example. What am I doing wrong here?

```
...
if ["$ANSWER" == "S"]
then
    ANSWER= set grid
else
    ANSWER=""
    echo "you want the plot whit boxes with lines or with points?"
    read HOW
    if ["$HOW" == "boxes"]
    then
        P= boxes
    else if ["$HOW" == "lines"]
    then
        P= lines
    else if ["$HOW" == "points"]
    then
        P= points
        gnuplot <<EOF
   ...
   fi
```

Comment: It says `expecting "fi"`...

Comment: `[` and `]` are keywords so must be separated (yes, both sides) from other text or punctuation with a space.

Comment: I've restructured your code so that it's indented properly. Perhaps you can see the `if`...`fi` issue yourself now.

Comment: `else if` should be written as `elif` in shell scripts

Comment: Your assignment statements won't do what you think they will do. `A=one` is not the same as `A= one`. The first assigns the string `one` to the variable `A`. The second sets `A` empty and runs the command `one`. Review your own code as pasted here to identify which form you're using and determine whether it's really correct, or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a corrected version of the if/then/elif/fi section of your script:

```
if [ "$ANSWER" == "S" ]
then
    ANSWER='set grid'
else 
    ANSWER=""
fi

echo "you want the plot with boxes, with lines, or with points?"
read HOW

if [ "$HOW" == "boxes" ]
then
    P=boxes
elif [ "$HOW" == "lines" ]
then
    P=lines
elif [ "$HOW" == "points" ]
then
    P=points
fi
```

Note the lack of a space after the `=` when setting `ANSWER` and `P`, and the use of `elif` rather than `else if`.  i've also added a space between `[` and the variables being tested `[boxes` or `[S` is not the same as `[ boxes` or `[ S`.  The former tries to run, e.g., the command `[boxes` while the latter runs `[` with an argument of `boxes`.

I've also put quotes in `ANSWER='set grid'`, without them it will set `ANSWER=set` and then try to run a command called `grid`.  Technically, there should be quotes on the `P=` lines too, but with only a single word (no spaces) after the `=` it doesn't need them.

---

Personally, i'd put the `then`s on the same lines as the `if` and `elif` because i think it makes it much more readable, but that doesn't matter - it's just a style preference, the code works the same either way.

```
if [ "$HOW" == "boxes" ] ; then
    P=boxes
elif [ "$HOW" == "lines" ] ; then
    P=lines
elif [ "$HOW" == "points" ] ; then
    P=points
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to end **each** `if` statement with `fi` in sh. Like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

BANANA=1

if [ $BANANA -eq 1 ]; then 
   echo "Banana was 1"
else
    echo "Oops"
fi
echo "This line will always be run"
```

That is, you need one `fi` for each `if` in your program, and the location of the `fi` determines where the code that is only sometimes executed ends.

Comment: Ok thanks. Excuse me for the stupid question.

Comment: @don_cristi: Fair enough! I'll correct it.